# How to load TinyMCE Editor through WebView within jar?

Tags: jar, webview, tinymce, javafx-2

In my JavaFX project, I am trying to integrate the **TinyMCE editor** as a HTML rich text editor via `WebView`. Here is a demo app:

```
package tinydemo;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TinyDemo extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Demo");
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        webView.getEngine().load(TinyDemo.class.getResource("simple.html").toExternalForm());
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(webView);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

I am using Netbeans IDE, the package view is:

[image: package]

The content of `simple.html` :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Simple theme example</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.5.2.min.js'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var wewe = document.getElementById('wewe');
                wewe.innerHTML += '<br/>protocol: '+ document.location.protocol;
                tinyMCE.init({
                    mode : "textareas",
                    theme : "simple"
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="wewe"></div>
        <h3>Simple theme example</h3>
        <textarea id="elm1" name="elm1" rows="15" cols="80" style="width: 80%">
                This is some example text that you can edit inside the &lt;strong&gt;TinyMCE editor&lt;/strong&gt;.
        </textarea>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            if (document.location.protocol == 'file:') {
                alert("The examples might not work properly on the local file system due to security settings in your browser. Please use a real webserver.");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, when I run the app from Netbeans, the TinyMCE editor loads successifully with the file protocol detected.

[image: build]

However, when I run the generated **TinyDemo.jar** from the command line under the folder **dist**, I get this:

[image: jar]

Where TinyMCE editor is failed to load. I think the problem is absolute/relative path references of TinyMCE within jar, but could not resolve it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

According to this [forum discussion thread](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2330194) relative resource loading currently only works correctly in the [2.1 developer preview](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html) of JavaFX and not in the 2.0GA version.

If, after upgrading to the 2.1 preview version of JavaFX, loading resources from a jar still doesn't work, then you could deploy TinyMCE on the classpath but outside of the packaged jar so that it is loaded using (for example) the file or http protcols rather than the jar protocol.  Or you can develop a custom protocol handler which loads resources from the jar as discussed in the referenced thread.

Comment: First of all, thanks **jewelsea** for suggestions. I have tried with version 2.1 dev preview with no luck. Since could not determine exactly where is a problem, cannot imagine what to write in a custom protocol handler. However, I have solved my problem by replacing the TinyMCE with more lightweight HTML editor.

Comment: Great you got it working Uluk.  If you need another example for embedding an editor you could see [embedding code mirror in JavaFX](http://jewelsea.wordpress.com/2011/12/11/codemirror-based-code-editor-for-javafx/), though that is for a syntax highlighting code editor and not a straight html editor.  Also JavaFX has a built-in [HTML editor](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/web/HTMLEditor.html) which I presume did not fit your needs.

Comment: Based on my tests with JavaFX version 2.2, I was also unable to get it to load tinyMCE when in a jar file. I suspect there may be something in tinyMCE that prevents it from working. My "solution" was to not put the tinyMCE code in a jar.